# Simplest way to pass information and notify a thread from another thread

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have C# application that calls a function from an unmanaged C++ DLL on a new thread when it loads up (on Windows). At this point they run as parallel threads and perform different tasks. the DLL function writes some information every once in a while to a memory mapped file. I want this function to send notification to the C# app after it finished writing to the MMF. it would be better this notification carry some number, but if that complicates things it's not a must.

**EDIT:**

What is happening in the entire process is that the C++ library is performing some heavy computation tasks, while the C# app is a WPF project that serves as a GUI, the C++ sends an update on its state as a very long vector of parameters, which is printed to the MMF (seems like a fast and organized way to do so). this information should be presented in the GUI.

In the comments it has been said that this using MMF is not a good practice here as all the activity is performed in the same process. I'm open for suggestions how to better plan this procedure.

Comment: If you want good advice, I think you'll need to explain more. For a start, what led you to select memory mapped files?

Comment: To me, it sounds like you want to pass some information from one thread to another, both running in the same process.

Comment: @helb guess you're right, edited

Comment: Memory mapped file is completely wrong here. This is an in-process problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i've edited the question's name and content, i'll be glad to hear what you have to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a delegate as callback function to the unmanaged function so it can notify the caller (C# app) when done.

Use a C++ function like this

```
void SetFinishedCallback(void (*callback)(bool success));
```

Then import the function in C# using

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void FinishedDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]bool success);

[DllImport("unmanaged.dll")]
private static extern void SetFinishedCallback(FinishedDelegate callback);
```

You should be able to call the function using

```
SetFinishedCallback(MyFuncAcceptingBool);
```

**EDIT:** Instead of passing a bool to indicate success / failure you could in principle also pass the entire result of your computation, no longer requiring the MMF. This raises the problem of marshalling since you must pass the data from unmanaged to managed code. If you have a simple data structure (like e.g. an array of byte) it would be easy.

In C++ use

```
void SetFinishedCallback(void (*callback)(void* data, int length));
```

In C# use

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void FinishedDelegate(IntPtr data, int length);
```

You have to convert the IntPtr manually in your callback method.

Comment: Exactly. If your app is calling a method on another dll, then the two threads are running inside the same process. No need for interprocess communication.

Comment: @RonTeller It's way too soon for code. First of all you need to decide what architecture you use. You cannot write code if you don't have a proper architecture in mind.

Comment: That solves the C++ - C# problem, but not the cross thread problem.

Comment: @Pete True, but as David Heffernan said, it is too early for code. The solution for thread safety would be implemented in the callback function and depends on the application design.